# How to identify sequences within each leaf from a regression tree?

Tags: r, decision-tree, traminer, sequence-analysis

Using the biofam dataset

```
library(TraMineR)
data(biofam)
lab <- c("P","L","M","LM","C","LC","LMC","D")
biofam.seq <- seqdef(biofam[,10:25], states=lab)
head(biofam.seq)

 Sequence                                    
1167 P-P-P-P-P-P-P-P-P-LM-LMC-LMC-LMC-LMC-LMC-LMC
514  P-L-L-L-L-L-L-L-L-L-L-LM-LMC-LMC-LMC-LMC    
1013 P-P-P-P-P-P-P-L-L-L-L-L-LM-LMC-LMC-LMC      
275  P-P-P-P-P-L-L-L-L-L-L-L-L-L-L-L             
2580 P-P-P-P-P-L-L-L-L-L-L-L-L-LMC-LMC-LMC       
773  P-P-P-P-P-P-P-P-P-P-P-P-P-P-P-P
```

I can fit and display a regression tree:

```
seqt <- seqtree(biofam.seq~sex + birthyr, data=biofam)

seqtreedisplay(seqt, type="I", border=NA, withlegend= TRUE, legend.fontsize=2, legendtext = "Biofam Regression Tree")
```

Then I can identify the leaf memberships:

```
seqt$fitted[,1]
```

This, however, is where I get confused. How do I know which leaf number corresponds to which leaf in the plot? The graph does not seem to display it, and running `print(seqt)` does not seem to give leaf numbers either.

What I would like to achieve is to separate out the sequences in each leaf, so that I can run descriptives on each leaf separately. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Currently, this information can not be easily recovered from the tree. The following function return a vector of the fitted values using full condition of the tree instead of the node label.

```
dtlabels <- function(tree){
    if (!inherits(tree, "disstree")) {
        stop("tree should be a disstree object")
    }

    split_s <- function(sp){
        formd <- function (x){
            return(format(x, digits =getOption("digits")-2))
        }
        str_split <- character(2)
        vname <- colnames(tree$data)[sp$varindex]
        if (!is.null(sp$breaks)) {
            str_split[1] <- paste("<=", formd(sp$breaks))
            str_split[2] <- paste(">", formd(sp$breaks))
        }
        else {
            str_split[1] <- paste0("[", paste(sp$labels[sp$index==1], collapse=", "),"]")
            str_split[2] <- paste0("[", paste(sp$labels[sp$index==2], collapse=", "),"]")
        }
        if(!is.null(sp$naGroup)){
            str_split[sp$naGroup] <- paste(str_split[sp$naGroup], "with NA")
        }
        return(paste(vname, str_split))
    }
    labelEnv <- new.env()
    labelEnv$label <- list()
    addLabel <- function(n1, n2, val){
        id1 <- as.character(n1$id)
        id2 <- as.character(n2$id)
        labelEnv$label[[id2]] <- c(labelEnv$label[[id1]], val)
    }
    nodeRec <- function(node){
        if(!is.null(node$split)){
            spl <- split_s(node$split)
            addLabel(node, node$kids[[1]], spl[1])
            addLabel(node, node$kids[[2]], spl[2])
            nodeRec(node$kids[[1]])
            nodeRec(node$kids[[2]])
        }
    }
    nodeRec(tree$root)
    l2 <- list()
    for(nn in names(labelEnv$label)){
        l2[[nn]] <- paste0(labelEnv$label[[nn]], collapse=" & ")
    }
    l3 <- as.character(l2)
    names(l3) <- names(l2)
    return(factor(factor(tree$fitted[, 1], levels=as.numeric(names(l3)), labels=l3)))

}
```

This function can then be used in the following manner.

```
fitted <- dtlabels(seqt)
print(table(fitted))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you are looking for the rules defined by the tree. You see them by looking at the the tree.

For example, the left most branch of your example `seqt` defines the rule:

```
birthyr <= 1940 & birthyr <= 1928
```

and the bottom left most leaf is defined by

```
birthyr <= 1940 & birthyr > 1928 & sex == "man"
```

I am afraid, however. that you are right. The `disstree` object returned by `TraMineR` (your `seqt`) does currently not explicitly contain that information. Perhaps in a further version.